# Taking screenshot from part of screen in swift

Tags: swift, screenshot

I Need to take a screenshot of a part of the screen.

This is the code to take a screenshot of the full screen:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let imageRef = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

But how do I take a screenshot from just a part of the screen?

Thank you

Comment: if the part of the screen is a UIView, check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-a-image

Answer (score 1):

1: You need to define a context. 
eg:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.messageTextView.bounds, true, 2.0 )
```

2: Draw image in context

```
self.messageTextView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.messageTextView.bounds.width, height: self.messageTextView.bounds.height), afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

3: Use newly drawn image

```
var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
self.someImageView.image = newImage
```

You can modify code to take screenshoot for your desired view.

Answer (score 0):

You do it using .snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(BOOL). Like this:

```
exampleImageView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
```

Comment: Returns a new view object containing a snapshot of the screen’s rendered contents. For further info look Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**This is the best way to screenshot part of a screen. try that for twitter and facebook screenshot share functionality**.

```
 func shareButtonClickedToTwitter() {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100,150), false, 0)
     var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     self.view?.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(-50, -50, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
     var screenShot  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     self.vc.showTWShare("I scored \(score) in Beanystalk can you do better? Available in App Store..", shareImage: screenShot)  
}
```